# Find and replace the data in text file using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a text file which is to be uploaded in the UI. The text file needs to be updated every time before the test runs. I need to capture this in my Selenium C# script.

Below is the data format:

```
0                 01CBA       Sou                  301500PAYMEN72    080416                                        
1062-000 14138 130000000012ROSY                            DEBITFROM
```

`080416` is the date. I need to replace it with system date every time the script runs.

How can I get the position of the date and replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I could use a regular expression to replace the date:

```c#
// load the file
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\yourfile.txt");

// replace the date
string text2 = Regex.Replace(text, @"\b080416\b", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyy"));

// save the updated text to a temp file
string tempPath = string.Format("{0}myfile-{1:X}.txt", Path.GetTempPath(), DateTime.Now.Ticks);
File.WriteAllText(tempPath, text2);

// upload the file
driver.FindElementByCssSelector("input[type=file]").SendKeys(tempPath);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. Can it be more generic, because 080416 is not constant. It will change every time the file is edited and saved. But the position of the string will be the same.

Comment: @SachuDev, you could also use this regex to match a unknown date: `\b[0123]\d[01]\d1\d\b`

Comment: Thanks Florent B for your answer.

Comment: I used the below code to resolve the issue:
var reader = new StreamReader(filepath);

 var str = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
var replacedString = str.Replace(str.Substring(74, 6), DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy"));
               
var writer = new StreamWriter(filepath);
               
writer.Write(replacedString);
               
writer.Close();